# delete spacing between rows in Gridview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I am using Gridview to put the images inside it, I split one image into small pieces of equal length and width e.g number of column=4 and number of rows=4
then I put the pieces in ArrayList
when I put the number of column equal count of pieces e.g 4 I get more space between the rows but when I put the number of column equal 2 I don't get more space and it is ok.
what I should do to put the number of column as I split it e.g 4 in the example and not 2 !

Note: the width of large image before the split equal width of screen.

```
this is my grid view 

<GridView 
          android:id="@+id/vincentgridview"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:horizontalSpacing="5dp" 
          android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true"

          android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
          android:layout_marginTop="30dp"              >
```

and this is grid view item

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete this lines

```
android:horizontalSpacing="5dp" 
android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
```

or Change to..

```
android:horizontalSpacing="0dp" 
android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
```

It should work fine.

Comment: it is not working :(, it is just delete 5 dp between the column and row, but also I need this space, but plus space in the rows I want to delete them.

Comment: set imageview scaletype to fitxy

Comment: thank you, no more space now, but the small image not square now, it is stretched to be vertical

Comment: then delete android:stretchMode="columnWidth"

Comment: it is still stretch, but thank you it is good and Acceptable :)

Comment: Well , scaleType to fitxy makes the image to take all available space of the imageview. So, if you want it to be square then you have to keep width and height same. then it will look perfect square. In your case , you can use fill parent for layout_width and layout_height for your imageview. It will solve your problem. If it helps , don't forget to hit the accept button :D Cheers...

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```